# Xcode 4.2's Organizer has high lag while archiving

Tags: xcode, loading, archive, lag, organizer

I'm just very curious if somebody has same problem as me. 
Every time I hit Archive, then Submit or Share, or Validate, Organizer becomes very hard to respond. Mac's loading cursor appears, almost all the time, and Organizer becomes incredibly slow on responding and navigation. Sometimes I have to press 3 or 4 times on Next button to get to next windows, in Submit process.

[image: Activity Monitor for xCode]

Any idea why is this happening?

Notes:

1. I reinstalled my xCode 4.2 recently, and this issue still persists.
2. I have an iMac i7, 3.4GHz, 16GB RAM, so I don't see the point of system overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is solved as I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.